# Does Elixir have other list operators besides `--` and `++`?

Tags: list, elixir

The Elixir docs state:

> Two lists can be concatenated and subtracted using the ++/2 and --/2 operators

For example, `["a", "b", "c"] -- ["a", "b"]` produces `["c"]`.

However, `["a", "b", "c"] -- ["a", "b", "b", "q"]` also produces `["c"]`. I'm wondering if there's a built-in operator or function that would produce `false` or `nil` in this case, to indicate that the second list cannot be subtracted from the first. (Note: I can't use a set for this, because I'm dealing with non-unique lists.)

Are there other list operators? If so, where are they documented?

Answer (score 0):

## It appears not to (in version 1.0)

The list operators I mentioned are documented in Kernel: [`++`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#++/2) and [`--`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2).

I don't see any others operators there (unless you count [`in`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#in/2)), but at least I know where these come from.